# visual studio не показывает часть кода

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нету namespace, class и подключения библиотек

Comment: C# уже не тот...

Comment: Так напишите то, чего не хватает, никто не запрещает :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас **буквально** 1 строка кода. Начиная с C# 9.0 это допустимо, Visual Studio всё правильно отображает.

Почитайте про [top-level statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements).